# snakemake unpack with shell & conda

Tags: snakemake

I have the basic "input can be single end or paired end reads" problem for my snakemake pipeline. I'd like to use `unpack` if possible, since it seems designed for this situation (as illustrated in the answer for [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/37/add-complex-conditional-file-dependency)), but I also want to use `conda:`, which requires `shell:`. I believe that `shell:` will die if I have `{input.read2}` but it's not provided by `unpack()`. Is there any good way of getting around this besides either 1) creating 2 nearly identical rules 2) making an empty read2 (if single-end) and then creating an if-else in `shell` to check for whether read2 is empty. Neither is ideal.

Comment: Could you post the code you'd like to use for single-ended data, and the code you'd like to use for paired-ended data, please

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine your input function with a params function to generate the flags for either paired or single end.  Using the bowtie example from your link:

```py
def bowtie2_inputs(wildcards):
    if (seq_type == "pe"):
        return expand("{reads}_{strand}.fastq", strand=["R1", "R2"], reads=wildcards.reads)
    elif (seq_type == "se"):
        return expand("{reads}.fastq", reads=wildcards.reads)

def bowtie2_params(wildcards, input):
    if (seq_type == "pe"):
        return f'-1 {input.reads[0]} -2 {input.reads[1]}'
    else:
        return f'-U {input.reads}'

rule bowtie2:
    input:
        reads=bowtie2_inputs,
        index=bowtie2_index
    output:
        sam="{reads}_bowtie2.sam"
    params:
        file_args=bowtie2_params
    conda: <env>
    shell:
        "bowtie2 -x {input.index} {params.file_args} -S {output.sam}"
```

Not sure it's any better than the shell option.  I would use two rules with a ruleorder preferring the paired ends.  That would be easier to modify if you wanted say a different aligner or to change parameters for each case.  As is this requires a bit of jumping around to actually see what the rule does.

Comment: I didn't consider using a function in `params:` for creating the necessary format for the command. Thanks!